# Given the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}$, $0 \leq x \leq y$, $ y\geq 0$. . Find $P(Y < 1| X = 1)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Given the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}$, $0 \leq x \leq y$,

$ y\geq 0$. 
. Find $P(Y < 1| X = 1)$.

Attempt: $P(Y < 1| X = 1) \frac{P(Y<1, X = 1)}{P(X = 1)}$

Can someone please help me setting the problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Since $P(X=1)$ is zero, you need to use the [conditional density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Continuous_distributions)

Comment: In general to solve such a problem one needs the conditional density, standard formula. But in this case just looking is enough.

Comment: Then since P(X = 1) is zero it can't be in the denominator, so it is only possible for when it is positive. Then we can conclude that it will be zero since the joint pdf is defined with y always larger than x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the result is immediate based on the support of the joint distribution. The support of $f_{X,Y}$ is $$0\le x\color{blue}{\le y}$$ which means that $Y$ takes (with positive probability) only values that at least equal as the value of $X$. So, if $X=1$ then $Y$ takes with positive probability only values $y$ such that $$1\color{blue}{\le y}$$ or equivalently $$P(Y\ge 1\mid X=1)=1$$ which implies that the required probability is equal to $0$.